# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error on c#

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

Am trying to get a cell value from gridview in `repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit1_EditValueChanged` event. But am getting null value only then error show like this "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in that line.

How to get cell value in particular row from gridview in EditValueChanged Event ?

my code is this

```
 private void repositoryItemGridLookUpEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridLookUpEdit LookupEdit = sender as GridLookUpEdit;
        DataRowView SelectedDataRow = (DataRowView)LookupEdit.GetSelectedDataRow();



        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Description", SelectedDataRow["ProductDescription"]);
        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("UoM", SelectedDataRow["UnitofMeasure"]);
        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Quantity", SelectedDataRow["DefaultQuantity"]);
        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Price", SelectedDataRow["MRPPrice"]);
        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("TaxInPercentage", SelectedDataRow["Taxid1"]);
        gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("ProductKind", SelectedDataRow["ProductKind"]);

        getdisc = LookupEdit.EditValue.ToString(); // get display value & pass to comparision to find Discound

        object productkin = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["ProductDescrption"]);

        string productkind = productkin.ToString(); // Error Object reference not set to instance of object

        MessageBox.Show(productkind, "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Help me ?

Comment: Which line you got that error?Maybe there're typo in the column names (They're case sensitive)

Comment: @User2012384 - indeed. `ProductDescription` versus `ProductDescrption` (note the missing `i` in the second one).

Comment: if (LookupEdit == null) return;   after "as"

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hi User2012384 & Corak, Ya thanks now i solved that. I get value but I want to store the access db value to Unbound Column n Get that value. I hide that Unbound Column it is possible to get that value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Corak noticed : you've got a typo error (missing "i") when getting the row cell value :

```
object productkin = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["ProductDescrption"]);
```

As column "ProductDescrption" doesn't exist, the variable productkind is null. Replace this line with the following :

```
object productkin = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["ProductDescription"]);
```

Comment: Hi, ya i solved that. Is it possible to set SelectedDataRow["Value"] to Unbount Column and i need to get that cell value ??